# Why was Aladdin not aware that he is a Magi?

Tags: magi

In the beginning of the anime "Magi", one of the main characters Aladdin didn't know he was a Magi until one of the Djinn users told him.

However Judal knew since he was born that he is a Magi and what is the job he has to do.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of chapter 175, little is known of this situation.

However, it *is* known that Aladdin does not have the memories of his early childhood. Thus, he would not remember his rank as a Magi until he was reminded.

> Not much is known about Aladdin's past, but he has found out who he is and where he came from thanks to Solomon and Solomon's Wisdom. The first memories he has are being in the Room of Fortitude with Ugo, where he was taught everything he knows by him.
>
> — [Aladdin, *Magi* Wiki](http://magi.wikia.com/wiki/Aladdin#History)

That said, there are some speculations as to why this may be the case:

> - Because he is likely a descendant of Solomon, or some reincarnation of him, the memories may have been hidden to prevent some potential goal. 
>  - It may also be the case that Aladdin is not *actually* a Magi, but something else that appears as a Magi. Thus, he may never have known his purpose prior to losing his memories, either.

However, none of these are confirmed nor backed by substantial proof, so take them with a few (read: several) grains of salt.